# R convert string to time

Tags: r, string, time, formatting

I would like to convert a string to time. I have a time field where the string has only four digits and a letter (A or P). There is no colon between the digits showing it is a time. I would like to convert the string, which is 12 hours,  to a 24 hour time so I can drop the A and P.

Here is an example:

```
time = c("1110A", "1120P", "0420P", "0245P")
```

I'm looking for a time class that loos like this:

```
Answer= c('11:10', '23:20', '16:20', '14:45')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want it to be an actual `Date` class or do you want it to be a character? If you want it to be a `Date`, you also need a month/year identifier

Comment: Shouldn't the last one be `14:45` instead of `2:45`?

Comment: I'd like to be able to subtract two times from each other. If I can do that with a date class that would be fine. I realize I am showing character in the Answer variable. I could easily convert it once I get to that point.

Comment: The last item in this vector doesn't fit that description though, since it does have a colon. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question, you say that you want to be able to subtract these times. I think it makes the most sense to convert it to a `POSIXct` object. If you want a specific `day/month/year` you need to append it to your string like below, otherwise you can not specify one and it will assume the date is today:

```
date2 = as.POSIXct(paste0("01-01-2018 ", time, "m"), format = "%m-%d-%Y %I%M%p")

date2
#[1] "2018-01-01 11:10:00 EST" "2018-01-01 23:20:00 EST" "2018-01-01 16:20:00 EST" "2018-01-01 14:45:00 EST"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the function `strptime` to create dates from strings after making one small change to your strings.

```
time <- c("1110A", "1120P", "0420P", "02:45P")
time <- gsub(":", "", time)
time <- strptime(x = paste0(time, "m"), format = "%I%M%p")
```

`paste` is needed for `strptime` to parse with the format that we've given it. `%I` is an hour (00-24), `%M` is the minute and `%p` is for parsing AM/PM.

Once it's parsed as a date, you can use format for pretty printing, or use the normal operators on it like `+`, `-`, `diff`, etc....

`strptime` gives you a lot of flexibility when parsing dates, but sometimes you have to try a few things when dates are not in a standard format.

Comment: %I is hours as decimal (01 - 12)

Answer (score 2):

We could also use the `lubridate` functions to parse the format after `paste`ing the date

```
library(lubridate)
library(glue)
ymd_hm(glue("2018-01-01 {time}M"))
#[1] "2018-01-01 11:10:00 UTC" "2018-01-01 23:20:00 UTC"
#[3] "2018-01-01 16:20:00 UTC" "2018-01-01 14:45:00 UTC"
```